# May I define aliases elsewhere than into .bashrc?

Tags: alias, bash

We are several persons using the same login id on Linux Box.

I want to define my own aliases without interfering with anyone.

In the `.bashrc`, I define a alias to my bash file defining my own aliases.

```
alias luc=/full/path/to/my/def_alias_luc.sh
```

The file /full/path/to/my/def_alias_luc.sh contains

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
echo "Defining Luc's aliases"
echo ""

echo ""
echo "aliases before..."
echo ""
alias
alias vimluc="vim -u /full/path/to/my/.vimrc "
echo ""
echo "aliases after"
echo ""
alias
```

After executing /full/path/to/my/def_alias_luc.sh, the alias is still undefined.

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want to *source* that file (i.e. run it within the existing bash process) rather than spawn off a *new* bash process (as the first line of the script would suggest you're doing) ?